# How to bootstrap an arch base system, probably without pacstrap

Tags: debian, ubuntu, arch-linux, container

I run an Ubuntu server on which I use `systemd-nspawn` to start containers. Containers need a base system which, in the case of Ubuntu, can be bootstrapped by `debootstrap`.

I would like now to try Arch. There is an equivalent to `debootstrap` called `pacstrap` but I could not find a version for Ubuntu (it looks like there used to be a PPA for this but it is now gone).

**Is there a solution to get this base system?**

- a version of `pacstrap` for Ubuntu?
- or a way to manually get the base system?
- or a standard place where to directly copy it from?

Comment: Nothing to do with Debian then... "Questions specific to the Debian official distribution (stable, testing, or unstable); if you are using a derivative of Debian (e.g. Mint, Ubuntu, Kali, etc), then use that distribution’s tag instead."

Comment: @arochester: isn't the deb in debootstrap for debian?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this web page: [Install from existing Linux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Install_from_existing_Linux), especially the subsection [From a host running another Linux distribution](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Install_from_existing_Linux#From_a_host_running_another_Linux_distribution).

Comment: Thank you. I just found a mention of the bootstrap package for Arch and the page you linked is exactly what i was looking for. I just bootstrapped an arch distro on my ubuntu.

Comment: Although I am surprised by the size of the image: the basic image with `base` installed is FOUR  times larger than the equivalent Ubuntu Zesty one.